# How to calculate this expression and get an integer number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

Hello there I don't have idea how to calculate this:

> $$\left[\frac {116690151}{427863887} \times \left(3+\frac 23\right)\right]^{-2} -  \left[\frac{427863887}{116690151} \times \left(1-\frac 8{11}\right)\right]^{-2}$$

I have tried dividing these numbers but couldn't get anything, also I get a 11/3 when I add and subtract these in brackets, but don't know how to use that.

Comment: Hi Milos. Please, be more detailed and provide your efforts. Your question is very badly posed at the moment and it is difficult to understand what you ask.

Comment: I don't have an idea how to get the result of this expression. That is all I need to calculate this expression.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha says it's 0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B116690151%2F427863887+*+%283%2B2%2F3%29%5D%5E%28-2%29+-+%5B427863887%2F116690151+*+%281-8%2F11%29%5D%5E%28-2%29) -- which should be a hint to how to simplify this. The things in square brackets are equal.

Comment: @1999, since $(3+2/3) = 11/3$ and $1-8/11 = 3/11$ the relation between the terms in the brackets is that of a recipricol. In other words, this is a number of the form $$x^2 - \frac{1}{x^2}$$ which is nonzero unless $x = \pm 1$.

Comment: @1999 I am not sure. WA performs really well on some problems and poorly on others. Another goof that WA made in a post I answered was saying that $2 \ln |x| - \ln(x^2)$ is nonzero. It's not a bad place to start, but I take everything I see on there with a grain of salt.

Comment: "I have tried dividing these numbers but couldn't get anything": you didn't try very hard, did you ?

Comment: @Joel Ah, but in fact $x=1$, because $116690151/427863887$ is just $3/11$.

Comment: @1999 Haha well that settles it then.

Comment: @Joel: WA does retranscript $2ln(|x|)-ln(x^2)$ as $0$. I'd say that it is more skilled for maths, especially complex computation, than $99.9999\%$ of people.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, my mistake. The specific query it got wrong was "does 2ln|x| equal ln(x^2)?" WA says this is false.

Comment: Indeed. It appears that the word "does" makes it interpret as a "simplify" command, which returns false (?). Without the "does", no problem, the expression translates to true. I agree that the "natural language" queries can be flawed.

Answer (score 2):

The two "small" fractions are $\frac {11}3$ and $\frac 3{11}$

Two methods of proceeding come to mind - the first is to see whether the factors $3$ and $11$ cancel (there are easy tests to show that both do), and see what happens.

The second would be to use the Euclidean Algorithm to see whether there are any common factors of the "large" fraction which can be cancelled out.

---

This is not a full answer, but you have not at the moment asked a really full question. When you get $\frac {11}3$ and you are working with fractions, then immediately you should test whether these cancel.

If you develop any intuition at all about this kind of problem, it should be that if you are having to do it by hand, something is likely to cancel somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple calculator, the big fraction is

$$r=0.27272727\cdots$$

Then $100r-r=27.27272727\cdots-0.27272727\cdots=27$ and 
$$r=\frac3{11}.$$

Indeed $\dfrac{116690151}3=\dfrac{427863887}{11}=38896717$.

The rest is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at just the part inside the first set of brackets:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac {116690151}{427863887} \times \left(3+\frac 23\right)
&=& \frac {116690151}{427863887} \times \frac{11}{3} \\
&=& \frac {116690151 \times 11}{427863887 \times 3} \\
&=& \frac {1283591661}{1283591661}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I think you can take it from there. A similar method works for the other part.

It may seem a bit unobvious that one should multiply $116690151 \times 11,$
since we usually want to separate the factors of the numerator and denominator
of a fraction we wish to simplify, but noticing that $11$ is not quite four
times $3$ and that $427863887$ is not quite four times $116690151$, 
one might hope that $\frac{427863887}{116690151}$ and $\frac{11}{3}$
might be equal, and cross-multiplying is one way to confirm that they are.
(As Mark Bennet remarked, if we're expected to work this out exactly
then we should look for things to cancel out, and we certainly get very
nice cancellation if the numbers we are multiplying are in fact
exact inverses.)